# WPF DataTemplate Lookahead/behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm using an ItemsControl that is populated with a collection containing several different data types. Each data type has its own DataTemplate, and they are all displaying correctly, but my problem is this: when there are several of the same type displayed one after another, the first one must display a header above it, and the last one must display a horizontal line below it. Is there a way to detect this in XAML, or do I need to pre-process this list a little to set flags?

The data is as follows:

```
Patient
Test
Result <-- header before this
Result
Result <-- line after this
Test
Result <-- header before, line after
Patient
Comment <-- header before this
Comment
Comment <-- line after this
Test
Result <-- header before, line after
```

I don't want to group the data types before displaying, they need to be displayed in the order in which they arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask next/prevous sibling of each item about its type, and compare it with current item's type, and take into account that if both are equal and equal to the item, you do nothing... definitely you cannot do this with pure xaml.

Te easiest way to me would be to implement two bool properties in the viewmodel of the items `'HeaderVisible'` and `'BottonLineVisible'` and handle the logic there. Bind triggers to them in the DataTemplate to add top/bottom line as needed.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I thought. Would be REALLY nice if I could get those values dynamically though. Oh well.

Comment: Do not let mvvm pattern make you neurotic. In the viewmodel is perfectly normal to have properties that exist only because of the view. As long as they are decoupled, this is, viewmodel could exist without the view (no reference to any element of the view in the viewmodel), it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit from binding your ItemsControl to a resource key of a CollectionViewSource defined somewhere.  You might be able to use the `CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions`[1]  to show this in the UI.

Look at `ItemsControl.GroupStyle`[2] for how to style this.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.groupdescriptions.aspx

[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It still involves code-behind, though, which is what I was hoping to avoid. Also looks like it might re-order the content like an SQL group, which would be bad.

Comment: So not exactly fitting of your requirements, but tell me, what is your aversion to code-behind?  Using code-behind to do something properly doesn't mean it is wrong.

Comment: Because it's part of display functionality, not anything to do with the data itself.

Comment: Many UI controls rely on logic, it's simply hidden within the class in the framework. It's up to you in which scope the logic is visible. If desired, it is extremely easy to package this functionality into a custom control that is based off of an ItemsControl.